# Kotlin: Accessing Enum Value generates nullpointerexception

Tags: class, kotlin, enums

I am trying to pass an enum as a parameter to another class, so I can override its price Value.
Here is my approach:

Base class Product:

```
open class Product(val productName: String, open val price: Double) {
    val profit = price
}
```

Enum class:

```
enum class Discount(val factor: Int) {
    BIGSALE(20),
    LITTLESALE(10),
    NOSALE(0)
}
```

Discount Product:

```
class DiscountProduct(
    val discount: Discount,
    productName_param: String, price_param: Double
) : Product(productName_param, price_param) {

    // Nullpointer Exception
    override val price: Double
        get() = super.price - ((super.price / 100) * discount.factor)
}
```

App (main):

```
val newProduct = DiscountProduct(Discount.BIGSALE, "Prod1", 100)
```

I appreciate every help. Thank you!

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DiscountProduct.getPrice(DiscountProduct.kt:6)
    at Product.<init>(Product.kt:2)
    at DiscountProduct.<init>(DiscountProduct.kt:3)
    at AppKt.main(App.kt:2)
    at AppKt.main(App.kt)
```

Comment: You should post the exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual constructor for `DiscountProduct`, when viewed as Java code, will look something like this:

```
public DiscountProduct(@NotNull Discount discount, @NotNull String productName_param, double price_param) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(discount, "discount");
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(productName_param, "productName_param");
    super(productName_param, price_param);
    this.discount = discount;
}
```

So the `super` constructor (i.e. `Product`'s constructor) is called first, and then the `discount` member is initialized.

`Product`'s constructor looks something like this:

```
public Product(@NotNull String productName, double price) {
    Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(productName, "productName");
    super();
    this.productName = productName;
    this.price = price;
    this.profit = this.getPrice();
 }
```

When you get to `this.profit = this.getPrice();` (which corresponds to the kotlin line `val profit = price`) you're calling `DiscountProduct`'s `getPrice` method, which tries to use the `discount` member, which hasn't yet been initialized. And that's why you get a `NullPointerException`.

---

There are probably a few different ways in which you could fix this. One possible solution would be to make `profit` a lazy property, so that it doesn't get initialized until the first time you try to use it:

```
val profit: Double by lazy { price }
```

Another possible solution would be:

```
val profit: Double get() = price
```

The difference between this and a lazy property is that here the price gets calculated every time you use `profit`, not just the first time.